# Decomposing a dilation into a composition of inversions

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked to show that that the dilation of $\mathbb{C}$ given by $z \mapsto 4z$ can be obtained composing three inversions--functions dfdof the form $z \mapsto \dfrac{1}{z-w}$ for some constant $w\in \mathbb{C}.$ I actually was able to figure out how to do this for any dilation, which I will repeat here in case anyone was curious

Set $\phi_1(z) = \dfrac{1}{z-w}$ and $\phi_2(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-w'}$, where the constants $w$ and $w'$ will be determined. Then observe

$$ \phi_2 \circ \phi_1(z) = \frac{z-w}{1-w'z+ww'}. $$

If we pick $w'$ such that $ww' = -1$, we will have

$$\phi_2 \circ \phi_1 (z) = w - \frac{w^2}{z}. $$

Now it's clear what the third inversion will be, we just send the whole thing back through $\phi_1$ to kill the $w$ and deduce

$$ \phi_1 \circ \phi_2 \circ \phi_1(z) = -\frac{1}{w^2}z, $$
and it's clear we can get any dilation by choosing $w$ appropriately. For the dilation $z \mapsto 4z$, we pick $w = \dfrac{1}{2i}$.

So, I have two questions. First, it's clear that this isn't unique, since we can interchange the roles of $w$ and $w'$ above and see that $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1 \circ \phi_2(z)$ gives the same dilation. But are there any others? And second, is there an intuitive way to do this geometrically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
\phi_1(z) = \frac{1}{z-a},\quad\phi_2(z) = \frac{1}{z-b},\quad\text{and}\quad\phi_3(z) = \frac{1}{z-c}.
$$
Then,
$$
\phi_3\circ\phi_2 \circ \phi_1(z) = \frac{1}{\frac{z-a}{1-bz+ab} -c} = \frac{-bz+(1+ab)}{(1+bc)z-(a+c+abc)}.
$$
For this composition to be a dilation we need some relations to be satisfied between $a,b$ and $c$ (as you implicitly noted):
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
1+ab &= 0, \\
1+bc &=0.
\end{aligned}
\Rightarrow b(a-c) = 0
\end{align}
$$
All of the above implies that none of the constants can be zero and that $a=c$, so it is *necessary* that $\phi_1 = \phi_3$. Using these conditions we un up with:
$$
\phi_3\circ\phi_2 \circ \phi_1(z) = -\frac{b}{a}z = -\frac{1}{a^2}z.
$$
This actually tells us that the inversions are *uniquely determined* once we know the factor of the dilation. If $f(z)=kz = \phi_3\circ\phi_2\circ\phi_1(z)$, then,
$$
a=\frac{1}{b} = c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-k}}.
$$